# get properties and attributes from XML using Linq in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, namespaces

I have a generated XML and need to extract properties attributes and BooleanValues

```
{<l7:Resource xmlns:l7="http:not shown for security reasons">
  <l7:TrustedCertificate id="not shown for security reasons" version="0">
    <l7:Name>not shown for security reasons</l7:Name>
    <l7:CertificateData>
      <l7:IssuerName>not shown for security reasons</l7:IssuerName>
      <l7:SerialNumber>not shown for security reasons</l7:SerialNumber>
      <l7:SubjectName>not shown for security reasons</l7:SubjectName>
      <l7:Encoded>not shown for security reasons</l7:Encoded>
    </l7:CertificateData>
    <l7:Properties>
      <l7:Property key="revocationCheckingEnabled">
        <l7:BooleanValue>true</l7:BooleanValue>
      </l7:Property>
      <l7:Property key="trustAnchor">
        <l7:BooleanValue>true</l7:BooleanValue>
      </l7:Property>
      <l7:Property key="trustedAsSamlAttestingEntity">
        <l7:BooleanValue>false</l7:BooleanValue>
      </l7:Property>
      <l7:Property key="trustedAsSamlIssuer">
        <l7:BooleanValue>false</l7:BooleanValue>
      </l7:Property>
      <l7:Property key="trustedForSigningClientCerts">
        <l7:BooleanValue>true</l7:BooleanValue>
      </l7:Property>
      <l7:Property key="trustedForSigningServerCerts">
        <l7:BooleanValue>false</l7:BooleanValue>
      </l7:Property>
      <l7:Property key="trustedForSsl">
        <l7:BooleanValue>false</l7:BooleanValue>
      </l7:Property>
      <l7:Property key="verifyHostname">
        <l7:BooleanValue>false</l7:BooleanValue>
      </l7:Property>
    </l7:Properties>
  </l7:TrustedCertificate>
</l7:Resource>}
```

I tried many solutions like

```
            public static void GetPropertiesWithAttributes(XElement certlist, XNamespace ns, IEnumerable<XElement> certProperties)
        {


            var propellor = from prop in certlist.Elements(ns + "Properties").Take(10)

                            select new
                            {
                                propAtt = (string)prop.Elements(ns + "Property").SingleOrDefault(PropertyElement => PropertyElement.Attribute(ns + "Key").Value == "trustAnchor"),

                                propBool = prop.Element(ns + "BooleanValue").Value
                            };

            foreach (var value in propellor)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"IENUMERABLE: {value}");
            }
        }
```

So I need to extract the properties like "trustAnchor" and the BooleanValue like "true". In order to get a list of those for all certificates in the store.
But they all result in null. So I am making the same mistake in all cases. Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: Create classes and deserialize your xml to it, you'd have anything you want.

Comment: you can use xml deserializer like this https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/simple-xml-parser-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion on deserialization. I tried that too, but it cant handle the amout of data especially the base64 string which is huge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<l7:Resource xmlns:l7='http:not shown for security reasons'>
            <l7:TrustedCertificate id='not shown for security reasons' version='0'>
                <l7:Name>not shown for security reasons</l7:Name>
                <l7:CertificateData>
                    <l7:IssuerName>not shown for security reasons</l7:IssuerName>
                    <l7:SerialNumber>not shown for security reasons</l7:SerialNumber>
                    <l7:SubjectName>not shown for security reasons</l7:SubjectName>
                    <l7:Encoded>not shown for security reasons</l7:Encoded>
                </l7:CertificateData>
                <l7:Properties>
                    <l7:Property key='revocationCheckingEnabled'>
                        <l7:BooleanValue>true</l7:BooleanValue>
                    </l7:Property>
                    <l7:Property key='trustAnchor'>
                        <l7:BooleanValue>true</l7:BooleanValue>
                    </l7:Property>
                    <l7:Property key='trustedAsSamlAttestingEntity'>
                        <l7:BooleanValue>false</l7:BooleanValue>
                    </l7:Property>
                    <l7:Property key='trustedAsSamlIssuer'>
                        <l7:BooleanValue>false</l7:BooleanValue>
                    </l7:Property>
                    <l7:Property key='trustedForSigningClientCerts'>
                        <l7:BooleanValue>true</l7:BooleanValue>
                    </l7:Property>
                    <l7:Property key='trustedForSigningServerCerts'>
                        <l7:BooleanValue>false</l7:BooleanValue>
                    </l7:Property>
                    <l7:Property key='trustedForSsl'>
                        <l7:BooleanValue>false</l7:BooleanValue>
                    </l7:Property>
                    <l7:Property key='verifyHostname'>
                        <l7:BooleanValue>false</l7:BooleanValue>
                    </l7:Property>
                </l7:Properties>
            </l7:TrustedCertificate>
        </l7:Resource>");

    XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("l7");

    var propellor = doc.Descendants(ns + "Property")
        .Where(d => d.Attribute("key").Value.Equals("trustAnchor"))
        .Take(10)
        .Select(prop => new
        {
            propAtt = (string)prop.Attribute("key").Value,
            propBool = prop.Element(ns + "BooleanValue").Value
        });

    foreach (var value in propellor)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"IENUMERABLE: {value}");
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
IENUMERABLE: { propAtt = trustAnchor, propBool = true }
```

Comment: Looks great now I have got to figure out how to get this working for an XElement instead of XDocument  because the XML is generated into an XElement.

Comment: Glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as answer.

Comment: Yes I got it to work by removing the .Root. Thank you very much Yitzak

Answer (score 1):

The attributes in your sample are **not** in a namespace so `PropertyElement.Attribute(ns + "Key")` is certainly wrong if that is the `ns` you also use to select the element nodes, it should simply be `PropertyElement.Attribute("Key").Value == "trustAnchor"` or `(string)PropertyElement.Attribute("key") == "trustAnchor"`.

Comment: Thanks, you are right about that. But my output now is System.Xml.Linq.XContainer+<GetElements>d__39

Comment: What happens if you access e.g. `value.propBool` in the `foreach`?

Comment: What is the datatype you need/want to return? You are looking up "trustAnchor" but want that value also in the result?

Comment: Console.WriteLine($"IENUMERABLE: {value.propBool}"); gives the same System.Xml.Linq.XContainer+<GetElements>d__39. I need the attribute itself so the sting thustAnchor and wether it is true or false. So in the end a list of all certificates (base64 sting which is stored in "Encoded" and which is decoded elswhere in the solution) with their properies and whether they are true or false.

Comment: Got it to work now. Thanks for your help!